# Move/Paste code not responding properly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to VBA user-forms so hopefully it's an easy fix.

I am using this code to move my entries from one sheet to another within the same workbook,but its working with some errors.

[image: Error No:1]

[image: Error No:2]

[image: Error No:3]

[image: Error No:4]

*I want it work on a specific sheet but its working on the active sheet.

**I want that after moving entries it should auto clear the specific sheet ( and I don't know how to do that :( )

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click() 'Move Button
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily").Range("endRange")
        If IsDate(cell) = True Then
            myEndRow = cell.Row

        End If

    Next cell

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily").Range("A2:E10000" & myEndRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Data").Select

    'Range("A2660").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("a99999").End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell(2).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Here is the link for the file: 
[Link](https://ufile.io/meh9t)

Comment: start by fully qualifying ranges e.g.  Range("a99999").End(xlUp).Select will use the ActiveSheet as you haven't fully qualified with e.g.  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(myWorksheetName).Range("a99999").End(xlUp).Select

Comment: (1) First thing to fix should be: Avoid using `.Select` or `Selection.` this is very bad practice and makes you run into many issues. There are many tutorials how to avoid them, just google or search on Stack Overflow. (2) Second you should specify a worksheet for **every** `Range`, `Rows` etc. like `Worksheets("MySheet").Range` or `set MyWs = Worksheets("MyWs")` and then `MyWs.Range`. (3) `"A2:E10000" & myEndRow` will result in `"A2:E10000100"` if `myEndRow` is 100 but I assume you mean something like `"A2:E" & 10000 + myEndRow` which results in `"A2:E10100"`. (4)Try to fix and then come back

Comment: Plus your For loop looks a bit odd - you are just finding the last cell containing a date?

Comment: Does the sheet Daily exist? And do you have a named range called endRange? And declare cell as range.

Comment: @QHarr yeah sheet daily is existing. and thank you for your point i added endrange.

Comment: After making the amendments suggested above did you still receive an error and if so which?

Comment: @QHarr ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(myWorksheetName).Range("a99999").End‌​(xlUp).Select its still just working with active sheet,if i select Daily sheet its showing error :(

Comment: if i run the code from sheet ("Daily") its working okay.but when i used the userform from sheet 1 its showing the error on range line.

Comment: (1) Please [edit] your question and update it to your actual code. (2) Did you do what I said and avoided all the `.Select` and `Selection.`? If not do this first! Otherwise the errors won't vanish. (3) You need to be much more specific and detailed otherwise we won't understand what you did.

Comment: All of your ranges should be fully qualified

Comment: @QHarr i updated my post with file link.please help me out i will be very grateful to you.my code working perfectly on sheet "Daily",but its showing errors if i run it from sheet "Data".

Comment: @qharr i created this vba code to move my daily enteries from Daily sheet to Data sheet. I iust wanted that my code just copy/paste all daily enteries till my last entery and paste it on data sheet on the last empty row.

Comment: Do you want it to copy everything in Daily copied across into Data and added at the next available free row? I.e. appended to any existing data and then the daily sheet to be cleared of all entries?

Comment: Yeah :) thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your daily sheet in the code associated with the button put the following.
Please note i am not sure of the purpose of your test to see if there is a date. If you can clarify this i can amend the code accordingly. You don't need a button in the data sheet as this is where you are copying to. Make sure this code only resides in the sheet associated with the button i.e. Daily and does not exist elsewhere in the workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Move Button

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim rangeToCopy As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Daily")
Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Data")

Dim NextRow As Long

NextRow = wsTarget.Cells(wsTarget.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Find next free row in Data sheet

Set rangeToCopy = wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0) 'get current set of rows that have data excluding header in daily sheet

rangeToCopy.Copy wsTarget.Cells(NextRow, "A") 'copy the new data from daily across to the next free row in the data sheet

rangeToCopy.ClearContents 'clear the contents of the daily sheet under the header


End Sub
```